# Left Join with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have 3 tables i.e. Client, Credit and Payment. I want get All payments and Credits made by a client between @StartDate and @EndDate. Here is my Query:

```
SELECT         Client.Name, Payment.PaymentAmount, Credit.CreditAmount
FROM            Client  

LEFT JOIN Payment 
ON Client.ClientID = Payment.ClientID 
LEFT  JOIN Credit
ON Client.ClientID = Credit.ClientID 

WHERE       (Payment.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND (Client.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
ORDER BY Client.CName
```

I want to show all the credits even if payment has not made against it with credit and NULL for payments, and vice-versa. But I can't get it, as it only shows the client with both credit and payment in that date.

I have tried OR instead of AND (with 'WHERE') But it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want by moving the conditions to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT c.Name, p.PaymentAmount, cr.CreditAmount
FROM Client c LEFT JOIN
     Payment p
     ON c.ClientID = p.ClientID AND p.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate LEFT JOIN
     Credit cr
     ON c.ClientID = cr.ClientID AND cr.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
ORDER BY c.CName;
```

However, I'm not sure that this is what you *really* want, because it is doing a cartesian product between payments and credits, where that are more than one during the time period.

This may be what closer to what you really want:

```
SELECT c.Name, p.PaymentAmount, NULL as CreditAmount
FROM Client c LEFT JOIN
     Payment p
     ON c.client_id = p.ClientId AND p.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
UNION ALL
SELECT c.Name, NULL, c.CreditAmount
FROM Client c LEFT JOIN
     Credit cr
     ON c.ClientID = cr.ClientID AND cr.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
ORDER BY Name;
```